# Bing Translator API returns incorrect Greek words

Tags: javascript, node.js, microsoft-translator

I'm using axios to do a GET request to the Microsoft Text Translator API. The call is successful and it properly returns translations from Greek to English. However, when I try to do an English to Greek translation, the answer is wrong. For example this is the translation for word "**προγραμματισμός**" comes out as `ÀÁ¿³Á±¼¼±Ä¹Ã¼ÌÂ` instead of `programming`. Has anyone encountered this problem with Greek or another language?

**index.js**

```
bp.hear(/μετάφρασε (.+)/i, (event, next) => {
const microsoft_translator_text = event.captured[0];
const requst = 
    axios.post("https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken", null, {
      headers: {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': bing_translator_api}
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      var microsoft_translator_auth = response.data;
      console.log(microsoft_translator_text);
      axios.get(`http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Ajax.svc/Translate?appId=Bearer%20${microsoft_translator_auth}&from=el&to=en&text=${microsoft_translator_text}`)
      .then(function (translation) {
        var translation_morph = translation.data.replace(/['"]+/g, '')
        event.reply('#translation', {
         translation: translation_morph,
        }) 
       })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
})
```

Comment: looks like an encoding issue. Are you assuming the text is ascii?

Comment: @Fai Not exactly sure. But I just tried to return something with quotes and the actual return I get is `&quot`.

Answer (score 0):

As Fai said this was an encoding issue. The problem is solved by using `encodeURI` on the url before sending it, like this:

```
var encoded_url = encodeURI("http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Ajax.svc/Translate?appId=Bearer " + `${microsoft_translator_auth}&from=el&to=en&text=${microsoft_translator_text}`)
axios.get(encoded_url, null, {
  headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'},
})
```